# WPDB function not saving

Tags: functions

This is my code:

```
 $wpdb->insert(
    'wpbi_contacts',
    array(
        'regname'                => $formData['regname'],
        'razon'                  => $formData['razon'],
        'email-1'                => $formData['email-1'],
         'descripcion'           => $formData['descripcion'],
         'categoria'             => $formData['categoria'],
         'nit'                   => $formData['nit'],
         'telefono'              => $formData['telefono'],
         'departamento'          => $formData['departamento'],
         'ciudad'                => $formData['ciudad'],
         'direccion'             => $formData['direccion'],
         'lineanegocios'         => $formData['lineanegocios'],
         'paginaweb'             => $formData['paginaweb'],
         'facebook'              => $formData['facebook'],
         'instagram'             => $formData['instagram'],
         'productosyservicios'   => $formData['productosyservicios'],
         'certificaciones'       => $formData['certificaciones'],
         'esecologica'           => $formData['esecologica'],
         'nombreencargado'       => $formData['nombreencargado'],
         'telefonoencargado'     => $formData['telefonoencargado'],
         'emailencargado'        => $formData['emailencargado'],
         'departamentoencargado' => $formData['departamentoencargado'],
         'ciudadencargado'       => $formData['ciudadencargado'],
         'direccionencargado'    => $formData['direccionencargado'],
         array('%s')
     )
 );
```

This is my log no errors:

```
[15-May-2020 17:52:59 UTC] Array
(
    [_wpcf7] => 2802
    [_wpcf7_version] => 5.1.7
    [_wpcf7_locale] => en_US
    [_wpcf7_unit_tag] => wpcf7-f2802-p2718-o1
    [_wpcf7_container_post] => 2718
    [regname] => Precisoft Inc
    [razon] => Diego Bonilla
    [nit] => 8004561465
    [telefono] => 4256873105
    [email-1] => dfbonilla@hotmail.com
    [departamento] => Granda
    [ciudad] => ISSAQUAH
    [direccion] => 20045 SE 127TH ST
    [categoria] => Alimentos
    [lineanegocios] => Productos
    [descripcion] => xx
    [paginaweb] => http://www.agro-vida.com
    [facebook] => http://www.agro-vidfa.com
    [instagram] => http://www.agro-vidfa.com
    [productosyservicios] => xxx
    [certificaciones] => xxxx
    [esecologica] => xxxxx
    [nombreencargado] => BONILLA DIEGO F (INT)
    [telefonoencargado] => 14256873105
    [emailencargado] => dfbonilla@hotmail.com
    [departamentoencargado] => granda
    [ciudadencargado] => ISSAQUAH
    [direccionencargado] => 20045 SE 127TH ST
)
```

the row don't store in the table. all columns are varchar.
It worked at some point but stopped workng,

THANK YOU

Answer (score 0):

It could also be the result of this known bug:

https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/32315

If your data is larger than the varchar field length then $wpdb->insert will fail and produce no errors.

If you don't mind data being truncated if it's larger than the field length, switch to $wpdb->query($wpdb->prepare(..)).

Because of this stupid bug I haven't used insert in years.

Answer (score -1):

Firstly what does it return? 0 for no rows inserted? or [false for error](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/insert/)?

```
$return_value = $wpdb->insert( ... );
var_dump($return_value);
```

Secondly, it looks malformed to me `array('%s')` is in your second argument but should be your third.

```
$wpdb->insert(
    'wpbi_contacts',
    array(
        'regname' => $formData['regname'],
        'razon' => $formData['razon'],
        'email-1' => $formData['email-1'],
        'descripcion' => $formData['descripcion'],
        'categoria' => $formData['categoria'],
        'nit' => $formData['nit'],
        'telefono' => $formData['telefono'],            
        'departamento' => $formData['departamento'],
        'ciudad' => $formData['ciudad'],
        'direccion' => $formData['direccion'],
        'lineanegocios' => $formData['lineanegocios'],
        'paginaweb' => $formData['paginaweb'],
        'facebook' => $formData['facebook'],
        'instagram' => $formData['instagram'],              
        'productosyservicios' => $formData['productosyservicios'],
        'certificaciones' => $formData['certificaciones'],
        'esecologica' => $formData['esecologica'],
        'nombreencargado' => $formData['nombreencargado'],
        'telefonoencargado' => $formData['telefonoencargado'],                          
        'emailencargado' => $formData['emailencargado'],
        'departamentoencargado' => $formData['departamentoencargado'],
        'ciudadencargado' => $formData['ciudadencargado'],
        'direccionencargado' => $formData['direccionencargado'],
        array('%s')
    )
);
```

Comment: Agreed. It looks to me like the `array('%s')` is meant as the `$format` arg, and should be outside of the array instead of inside it. Check the [`wpdb::insert()` docs](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/insert/).